# Another Navigation Controller and View Controller Question

Tags: iphone, view, navigation, controller

I have a NavigationController based app. TableViewController loads Array. User clicks Cells and Xib(view controller) is pushed to top of stack. Question is, Can I load another Xib off the Current Xib...Thanks

Comment: What language is this in? What development environment? More information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand if you want that the other xib pop's out automatically when the first xib is already viewed.

If yes, you can put a initialization code in `(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` of the first xib controller that inits the other xib:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    viewController = [[PorcentagemPadraoOpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OtherXib" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES]; 
    [viewController release];

}
```

Hope that helps you.